# Is there any point of refactoring LUT array to case statement?

Tags: delphi, refactoring

I've got the following LUT (lookup table) for retrieval of display name for pseudo-PChar (all these predefined PChars are integers under their skin, you know) input:

```
const
  RT_MIN = DWORD(RT_CURSOR);
  RT_MAX = DWORD(RT_MANIFEST);

  ResourceTypes: array [RT_MIN..RT_MAX] of PChar = (
    'Hardware-dependent cursor',
    'Bitmap',
    'Hardware-dependent icon',
    'Menu',
    'Dialog box',
    'String-table entry',
    'Font directory',
    'Font',
    'Accelerator table',
    'Application-defined resource (raw data)',
    'Message-table entry',
    'Hardware-independent cursor',
    nil, { unknown, reserved or not used }
    'Hardware-independent icon',
    nil, { unknown, reserved or not used }
    'Version',
    'Dialog Include',
    nil, { unknown, reserved or not used }
    'Plug and Play',
    'VxD',
    'Animated cursor',
    'Animated icon',
    'HTML resource',
    'Side-by-Side Assembly Manifest'
  );
```

Will I get any advantages/disadvantages in rewriting that as `case` statement? Are there any advantages/disadvantages in leaving that as is?

Comment: Does it work? Is it easy to maintain? Is performance good? (I.e. Not being red-flagged by profiling tests.) If you answered yes to these questions then the most important disadvantage of rewriting is that it would be a waste of your time. I'm sure you can find more productive uses for your time.

Comment: You would do best to test (profile) this yourself, but in my experience, a LUT is faster than a `case` construct. In the best optimized case, the `case` construct uses a LUT, but you can't be sure of that. So simply profile it. I see no advantage in using `case`.

Comment: What are your criteria to judge things? The question seems pretty vague and unfocused.

Comment: Assuming you were addressing me? My experience with such scenarios and profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using an array is the fastest method. If you e.g. query `ResourceTypes[2]`, the program will first look at `ResourceTypes[2]`, dereference the PChar and output the zero terminated string. If the compiler is smart, it could recognize that the strings are unchangeable and so it could place all strings directly in the array, so you would save one dereferencing operation. (For those who are interested in it, can view the memory contents using an hex-editor like HxD to check if this is true or not).

Another problem which might happen in future could be following scenario: Let's say Microsoft defines a new resource type which is something very special, and so it gets a large number like $FFFF . If you are using `case of`, you can simply add 2 lines of code to add this new resource type. By having a lookup-table (or LUT, this abbreviation is new to me), you would have a problem then, since you would need to create an array with size 65535 whose contents are to 99% just `nil`s.

I would accomplish it by creating a function:

```
function GetHumanFriendlyResourceTypeName(AResourceType: PChar): string;
begin
  if not Is_IntResource(AResourceType) then
  begin
    result := AResourceType;
  end
  else
  begin
    case Integer(AResourceType) of
      Integer(RT_CURSOR):
        result := 'Hardware-dependent cursor';
      Integer(RT_BITMAP):
        result := 'Bitmap';
      Integer(RT_ICON):
        result := 'Hardware-dependent icon';
      Integer(RT_MENU):
        result := 'Menu';
      Integer(RT_DIALOG):
        result := 'Dialog box';
      Integer(RT_STRING):
        result := 'String-table entry';
      Integer(RT_FONTDIR):
        result := 'Font directory';
      Integer(RT_FONT):
        result := 'Font';
      Integer(RT_ACCELERATOR):
        result := 'Accelerator table';
      Integer(RT_RCDATA):
        result := 'Application-defined resource (raw data)';
      Integer(RT_MESSAGETABLE):
        result := 'Message-table entry';
      Integer(RT_GROUP_CURSOR):
        result := 'Hardware-independent cursor';
      Integer(RT_GROUP_ICON):
        result := 'Hardware-independent icon';
      Integer(RT_VERSION):
        result := 'Version';
      Integer(RT_DLGINCLUDE):
        result := 'Dialog Include';
      Integer(RT_PLUGPLAY):
        result := 'Plug and Play';
      Integer(RT_VXD):
        result := 'VxD';
      Integer(RT_ANICURSOR):
        result := 'Animated cursor';
      Integer(RT_ANIICON):
        result := 'Animated icon';
      Integer(RT_HTML):
        result := 'HTML resource';
      Integer(RT_MANIFEST):
        result := 'Side-by-Side Assembly Manifest';
      else
        result := Format('(Unknown type %d)', [Integer(AResourceType)]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is a demonstration of the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Hardware-dependent icon
  ShowMessage(GetHumanFriendlyResourceTypeName(MAKEINTRESOURCE(3)));

  // (Unknown type 123)
  ShowMessage(GetHumanFriendlyResourceTypeName(MAKEINTRESOURCE(123)));

  // AVI
  ShowMessage(GetHumanFriendlyResourceTypeName(PChar('AVI')));
end;
```

The performance is not as high as in your solution, but this function has several advantages:

1. This function is much easier to read since every `RT_` constant is standing in front of its human-friendly name. So the code is also much better to maintain. In the LUT, the human-friendly names could be accidently interchanged (also since no comment in front of each human-friendly name indicates the official `RT_` constant name).
2. This function does also show a nice human-friendly string "(Unknown type 123)" if the identifier is unknown.
3. This function will also dereference the string if it is not a predefined type (`RT_`)
4. Using this function you can internationalize your application either statically by putting the strings into resourcestrings or dynamically by querying a translation function/stringlist.

Comment: (0) It is safe to prune pointer to 16 least significant bit using `Word(IntResPtr)`. (1) But your idea of someone unintentionally corrupting typed **constant* is a bit strange. (2a) Yeah, the inconvenience with `RT_xxx` gaps was the one of my concerns (I have post-checking against `nil`s retrieved from LUT). (2b) Having `RT_xxx` constant and display name side-by-side is also looks more maintainable than just an array. Sorry, comments at SO does not allow any paragraph formatting so I cant separate preceding sentences unrelated to each other.

Comment: About your point #0, I had finally found the function `Is_IntResource` . In the first version of my answer I was unsure if it is really the first 16 bits also for 64 bit systems and searching in MSDN is a pain in the b... Sorry, I had overseen the `const` in your question. So I have removed that issue. But if you noticed, I have added another issue: If Microsoft adds a resource identifier which is not sequencial to the existing ones, e.g. $FFFF, you would have a big problem with a LUT implemented as simple array.

Comment: By the way, `array [...] of PChar` is not `resourcestring`-friendly, but I figured out what `array [...] of string` allows them, so from the localization point of view advantage is very minor.

Comment: Rather pointless making assertions about performance based on what you think. Measure it if you want to know. A good compiler could easily turn the case statement into the same LUT.

Comment: `Is_IntResource`, `Format`, the Delphi string handling (ARC etc.) as well as the function calls (putting everything on the stack and freeing it again) needs time, which was not the case of querying a constant array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In the best case, the `case` is converted to a LUT. But you can't be sure of that. If the `RT_` indices are contiguous, I don't see how anything could be faster than a direct array access. Of course, `PChar('AVI')` will not fit in that scheme and would need special processing.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'm advocating checking the output from the compiler, and also timing it. If you care about perf then you have to time. Guesswork doesn't cut it.

Comment: That is what I already said in an earlier comment. Profiling is necessary. But even then, IME, nothing can beat a LUT, and certainly not a case statement or a Dictionary, and I think I can safely say that without profiling. All this assumes that the indices are contiguous (with a few gaps allowed, where you simply return nil or an error message), of course. It gets more complicated if they are nothing near contiguous. Then, a perfect hash might be a fast solution.